# Can Running Boards Overlap?

Tags: electrical

This is a very basic question about running NM cable in accessible attics.

My attic has running boards perpendicular to 2x4 truss "web" members.  They are there but unused.

To get up to the existing running boards, I need to run several (6+) cables parallel to a 2x4.  Does it make sense to simply nail on another running board from the bottom of the truss and up over the existing running board?

Or, is it be better to add some 2x4 between two of the trusses to support the new running board?

I could see it working either way.  The extra 2x4s might look more pro?  I just wondered if there is a conventional way of doing this, because all of the examples of running boards look like they are perpendicular to the frame.

[image: Running boards not overlapping]

[image: Overlapping boards]

Comment: Several as in, I need to run 6 cables with space for more in the future.  Keeping all of that 1.25" away from the edge of a 2x4 seems like a real stretch of the rules and would be easier to just work with it all on a running board.  I'm sure there are ways around this but would like to know what's the best technique to add a running board parallel to the truss.

Comment: 300.4 was applicable, or I assumed so, because the attic is readily accessible and used for storage.

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words... Maybe annotate it with a few hand drawn red <s>circles</s>... lines... :)

Comment: I'll work on it.  Basically, a 2x4 truss with many cables needing to go half way up to where the running boards live.

Comment: Actually it looks a lot like this:

https://www.the-guide.com.au/home-guide/roof/web-bracing

These might be "web ties" in my attic

Comment: @FreeMan Added some rough sketches.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have some NM-B wiring that is in the floor of the attic space (somewhere near the vertical member of the truss at the right edge of the picture, I'd guess), and you need to run it up the truss to the horizontal support, then across to somewhere else. To support the wire for this (more or less) vertical run, you're looking to add some strapping as a "rat run" (is the term I've heard) or "running board".

I'd suggest that the simplest method would be to use your wire staples to attach the cables directly to one of the angled 2x4s that are a part of the truss itself. This takes no extra lumber of any sort and should be perfectly acceptable for supporting 1, 6 or even more wires. If you run out of space, you can run some of the cable horizontally to the next truss and run them up that one.

They don't make wire staples (to my knowledge) that will span 6 14/2 or 12/2 cables, but they do make supports that hold that many in a sort of clip in fashion. (I've seen them posted here, but don't recall what they're called, I'll edit in a link if I can find them.)

If, however, you want to add a piece of wood between two trusses, I can see no problem with doing so as shown in your second drawing. The purpose of the wood over a span like this is to prevent people from hanging things on the cable (not likely going to happen on a steep slope like that) which could potentially damage the cable and/or pull it away from its other supports (and, potentially, pull it out of the wire nuts), and to protect it from damage should something accidentally hit the cables. Having wood underneath the cable run would certainly provide the required protection in both cases.

I cannot see any issue with having the "vertical" board in your second drawing overlapping the horizontal one when the cable transitions from one to the other. Cables bump over things all the time. I think the only reason to go with your first drawing would be your personal preference for a somewhat more "tidy" looking appearance. There would certainly be a lot more work involved.

Also, I note that you spec a 1x6 in your first drawing and a 2x6 in the second. Unless you happen to have some spare lumber laying around, I can't imagine that there's any need whatsoever to use a 2x6 to support a few cables over a 2-4' run. Again, the board is for protection of the cable, and you'd have to hit a 1x6 *pretty darn hard* to break it and cause some sort of problem. That's something that you're not likely to do by accident when turning around in the attic with something in your hands (unless you happen to do some wild, flailing dancing in your attic while holding a running chainsaw in your hands).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Just a note, from the bottom of the joist diagonally up to those web ties is nearly 6 feet, so I was thinking a 1x6 alone might not be sturdy enough for hammering those staples and such work.  Also, cutting a couple or few 2x4s to support the board is not much work imo.

Comment: I'm still not sure, @RobertChapin, why you wouldn't just run them up the 2x4 of the truss itself... If you do choose to run an extra board, yes, I can see where a 1x wouldn't be stiff enough. Just cut a temporary brace to wedge in while nailing.